# How to fix "Unable to find FirebaseRecyclerOptions ” error in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm building my first android application, and i am stuck here. Where do I need to fix this error

I have tried checking my `gradle` but it didn't help

```
//swipe layout
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (getIntent() != null)
                foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra(Common.INTENT_FOOD_ID);
            if (!foodId.isEmpty() && foodId != null)
            {
                //Create request query
                Query query = ratingTbl.orderByChild("foodId").equalTo(foodId);

                // Error cant find symbol
                // This is exactly where i am stuck
                **FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Rating> options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions**
                LoadComment(foodId);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you might be missing this one: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Thanks Manjoj I just updated my ui library and it's working well